# Is sorting a DataFrame memory efficient?

Tags: python, pandas

Is sorting a DataFrame in pandas memory efficient? I.e., can I sort the dataframe without reading the whole thing into memory?

Comment: what would you consider "memory efficient" in this case? O(1) additional memory?

Comment: If it is able to sort without reading in the whole df would be a more precise question. Sort of like the magical thing `unix sort` does. Sorry for being too ignorant to ask the question properly.

Comment: What magical thing does `unix sort` do?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat No need to apologize. But please edit the question to include your definition of "memory efficient". Like you said, for future reference (btw, you can remove that part while editing)

Comment: Are you referring to [`External Sorting`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)? I guess that's not happening in `pandas`. Anyway: A `DataFrame` typically fits into your memory, if it does not, you cannot load it in the first place.

Comment: You can read a dataframe in chunks though. But thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, pandas relies on [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to do all the sorting.

That being said: pandas DataFrames are backed by numpy arrays, which have to be present in memory as a whole. So, to answer your question: **No**, pandas needs the whole dataset in memory for sorting.

**Additional thoughts:**

You *can* of course implement such a disk-based external sorting using multiple steps: Load a chunk of your dataset, sort it, save the sorted version. Repeat. Load a part of each sorted subset, join them into one DataFrame and sort it You'll have to be careful here on how much t oload from each source. For example, if your 1000 element dataset is already sorted, getting the top 10 results from each of the 10 subsets won't get you the correct top 100. It will, however, give you the correct top 10.

Without further information about your data, I suggest you let some (relational) database handle all that stuff. They're made for this kind of thing, after all.